# Dynamically construct variables inside the script and fetch values from source parameters

Tags: source

I have a txt file extract.dat which is read inside my code using source.

```
$ cat extract.dat
ExchgRate_prop="EDB_NAME=share_exchange SRC_WDS=wds PN=ExchgRate"
Compliance_prop="EDB_NAME=share_compliance SRC_WDS=wca PN=com"
Unitcost_prop=="EDB_NAME=share_unitcost SRC_WDS=wda PN=unit"

source ./ extract.dat
```

now I would have got all the varaibles inside my code.  if my code takes an argument $PROJ with value as 'ExchgRate'  , how can i concatenate "$PROJ""_prop" to create the variable ExchgRate_prop and then get value "EDB_NAME=share_exchange SRC_WDS=wds PN=ExchgRate"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bash *variable indirection*. Ex. given

```
$ echo "$ExchgRate_prop" 
EDB_NAME=share_exchange SRC_WDS=wds PN=ExchgRate
```

and

```
$ PROJ=ExchgRate
```

then

```
$ var=${PROJ}_prop
$ echo "${!var}"
EDB_NAME=share_exchange SRC_WDS=wds PN=ExchgRate
```

Comment: Perfect. That worked